# Is there a way to configure stick-table with both IPv4 AND IPv6?

Tags: haproxy

When configuring HaProxy to use Stick Tables, it's possible to use the IP of the user with the following command :

```
stick-table type ip size 1m expire 60s store conn_cur
```

The issue is that, from what I could find on the documentation, this only affects IPv4, not v6. In order to target IPv6, you need to have another stick table :

```
stick-table type ipv6 size 1m expire 60s store conn_cur
```

Which forces you to have two backends (one per stick table) and two sets of configuration for v4 and v6.

Is there a way to have only one stick-table for both IP versions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one `ipv6` stick table, delete the `ip` one. Fetching [src](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.3/configuration.html#7.3.3-src) into a 6 table will result in IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses.

```
src : ip
This is the source IPv4 address of the client of the session. It is of type
IP and works on both IPv4 and IPv6 tables. On IPv6 tables, IPv4 addresses are
mapped to their IPv6 equivalent, according to RFC 4291.
```